# Construction of nested model sequence in R

Tags: r, glm

For the subject of generalized linear models:

How to construct a nested sequence of (at least 100) models by adding one variable at time?

There is a base model_0, E(Y) = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2, which is a part of next complicated model.

The pattern is:

> 

```
model_1 = model_0+b3x1*x2
model_2 = model_1+b4x1^2
model_3 = model_2+b5x2^2
model_4 = model_3+b6x1^2*x2
model_5 = model_4+b7x1*x2^2
model_6 = model_5+b8x1^2*x2^2
model_7 = model_6+b10x1^3
model_8 = model_7+b11x2^3
model_9 = model_8+b12x1^3x2 
etc.
```

Task hints to use poly() and update() functions and the main task is to test AIC(model_o) against generated AICs of other generated models and apply test statistics.

Would be glad for any help with coding above pattern.

Comment: Create a list of `formula` objects representing your series of models; use `lapply` to iterate the model estimation function over that list of formulae; then use `sapply` with `AIC` to get a vector of AIC for those models. Or just fold the estimation and AIC computation into one call to `lapply` or `sapply` if you really don't need to do anything else with the model objects.

Comment: I am afraid my programming skills are far below than you expect. I only know how to navigate. Could you show me please the code. I know it sounds lazy, but I wish I could have time to try and experiment by myself.

Comment: No, sorry. You could always post a separate question about that problem. But at this point, you're just asking people to write all your code for you, and that's not what I'm here for.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to rely on the `leaps::regsubsets` to derive all combinations of a formula.

For example:
Using the `swiss` data-set, with `Fertility` as the response variable, I could rely on regsubsets to provide a logical matrix of all the difference combinations of predictor variables.

```
library(leaps)

mod <- regsubsets(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss, nvmax = 100, nbest = 10, really.big= T, method = "exhaustive")
head(summary(mod)$which[,-1])

  Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
1       FALSE       FALSE      TRUE    FALSE            FALSE
1       FALSE        TRUE     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
1       FALSE       FALSE     FALSE     TRUE            FALSE
1       FALSE       FALSE     FALSE    FALSE             TRUE
1        TRUE       FALSE     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
2       FALSE       FALSE      TRUE     TRUE            FALSE
```

To construct the models with the matrix for simple linear regression:

```
am <- summary(mod)$which[,-1]
pred <- lapply(1:nrow(am), function(x) colnames(am)[which(am[x,])])
lm.mod.form <- lapply(pred, function(x) paste0("lm(Fertility ~ ", paste(x, collapse="+"), ", data=swiss)"))

head(lm.mod.form)

[[1]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Education, data=swiss)"

[[2]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Examination, data=swiss)"

[[3]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Catholic, data=swiss)"

[[4]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Infant.Mortality, data=swiss)"

[[5]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture, data=swiss)"

[[6]]
[1] "lm(Fertility ~ Education+Catholic, data=swiss)"

all.mods <- lapply(lm.mod.form, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
```

To construct models with the matrix for a simple GAM model:

```
am <- summary(mod)$which[,-1]
pred <- lapply(1:nrow(am), function(x) colnames(am)[which(am[x,])])

gam.mod.form <- lapply(pred, function(x) paste0("gam(Fertility ~ s(", paste(x, collapse=") + s("), "), data=swiss)"))
head(gam.mod.form)

[[1]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Education), data=swiss)"

[[2]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Examination), data=swiss)"

[[3]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Catholic), data=swiss)"

[[4]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Infant.Mortality), data=swiss)"

[[5]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Agriculture), data=swiss)"

[[6]]
[1] "gam(Fertility ~ s(Education) + s(Catholic), data=swiss)"
```

EDIT:

```
gam.mods <- lapply(gam.mod.form, function(x)eval(parse(text=x)))

comparison.output <- data.frame(model=1:length(gam.mods), 
                                y="Fertility", 
                                x=sapply(1:length(pred), function(x)paste0(pred[[x]], collapse="+")))

comparison.output$AIC <- sapply(gam.mods, AIC)
comparison.output$BIC <- sapply(gam.mods, BIC)

comparison.output %>% arrange(AIC) %>% head

   model         y                                                          x      AIC      BIC
1    30 Fertility           Agriculture+Examination+Catholic+Infant.Mortality 288.4231 336.1923
2    29 Fertility          Agriculture+Examination+Education+Infant.Mortality 304.7265 341.6840
3    25 Fertility                       Agriculture+Catholic+Infant.Mortality 309.4141 353.7462
4    18 Fertility                      Examination+Education+Infant.Mortality 310.3209 344.5467
5    31 Fertility Agriculture+Examination+Education+Catholic+Infant.Mortality 312.9976 337.8481
6    27 Fertility             Examination+Education+Catholic+Infant.Mortality 316.8395 339.5171
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you wrote it that it looks so easy, I want to learn to be like that. Now my next question is to turn this list outputs into formulas, because I need to compare AICs of outputs. I tried: AIC(formula(gam.mod.form[1])) but that don't work.

Comment: you can't run `AIC` for `gam.mod.form` since that's only the command as how one would type in character format, e.g. `"gam(Fertility ~ s(Education), data=swiss)"`. You would need to run a  `parse` the command as text, and then evaluate it with `eval` to get run the gam. I'd made the edits above to extract AIC and BIC values for gam mods.

Comment: I don't think this solves this particular problem, because he wants to try various quadratic and cubic forms as well as just different combinations of variables.

Comment: Dear Adam, thank you very much, I am going to reach your level one day. ;)

Comment: p.s. ulfelder is right, the pattern above is a general theory to try different forms and compare them with model_0, idea is to test lack of fit of model_0. If AIC of model_0 higher than any other generated models, test is failed. However you applied it on practice. I will try to build that sequence myself, but your code above is huge help.

Comment: Why I have problems with using the above code on 'ustemp' dataset from 'SemiPar' library and 'min.temp' as a response? Adam could you help me please with your code.

Comment: `min.temp` as a reponse to what predictor? `latitude` and `longitude`?